# What's the difference between \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=2,y radius=2]; and \draw(0, 0) circle (2);?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I type in the two codes resulting two circles fit together, coinciding with each other. Then what's the difference between them?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle[x radius=2,y radius=2]; %this code means center point is (0, 0) with radius 2 
\draw(0, 0) circle (2); %this code means center point is (0, 0) with radius 2
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (14.6 The Circle and Ellipse Operations):

> Note: There also exists an older syntax for circles, where the radius
>   of the circle is given in parentheses right after the circle command
>   as in `circle (1pt)`. Although this syntax is a bit more succinct, it
>   is harder to understand for readers of the code and the use of
>   parentheses for something other than a coordinate is ill-chosen.

Thus, `circle (2)` is the older syntax and short for `circle[radius=2]`, which is an abbreviation for `circle[x radius=2, y radius=2`].