# Different dimensions with shift and xshift

Tags: tikz-pgf

I discovered that there is a different default dimension in shift and xshift.

Consider the following mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0,3) {a};
  \node (b) at (0,2) {b};
  \node (c) at (0,1) {c};
  \node (d) at (0,0) {d};
  \node[xshift=5cm] at (a) {aa};
  \node[shift={(5cm,0)}] at (b) {bb};
  \node[xshift=5] at (c) {cc};
  \node[shift={(5,0)}] at (d) {dd};
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives the following result:
[image]

For the two first lines given with 'cm' (a and b), the behavior of shift and xshift is the same.

But without dimensions (c and d) , it seems that shift uses default tikz dimensions, while xshift seems to use point?

I noticed that in the manual xshift is always given with cm, but this behavior is not explained.

Am I doing something incorrect? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: You're not doing anything incorrect, and this has been noticed before. Another situation in which the default unit is cm is a cricle, so `\draw (0,0) circle(1);`  gives you a circle of radius 1cm, similarly for arcs. As you have noticed, this is also true for coordinates, so `at (1,0)` and `at (1cm,0)` are equivalent. That's why the `shift={(5,0)}` and `shift={(5cm,0)}` can be used interchangedly. But for "most" other situations the default unit is `pt`.

Comment: I can understand that commands doing completely different actions have different default dimensions. But shift and xshift seem very close, at least in terms of functionality.  And this difference in behavior is really confusing...

Comment: I agree it is confusing. But in my list of confusing things this is below the confusion which library one has to load to make an example from the pgfmanual run through. (And I would like to draw your attention to [this source of confusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469747/how-does-tikz-parse-powers), which confuses me, too. ;-)

Comment: I guess the clearest discussion can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TikZ always the default unit for length values is `pt`. And we have

> `/tikz/xshift=<dimension>`

So the default unit for `xshift` is `pt`.

In `(1,0)` you can think of `cm` as default unit but there is no default unit. Simply `(1,0)` is `1.x+0.y` so it depends on the value of the `x` vector, which is initially set to `(1cm,0)`.

Comment: If "In TikZ always the default unit for length values is `pt`. " is really always true, why doesn't it apply to radii and the like? Or is in your opinion a radius not a length unit?

Comment: The manual is slightly more subtle. For the coordinates, it defines unit vectors (`x-vector`, `y-vector` and `z-vector`) which have by default a length of `1 cm`. *See page 366 of manual 3.1*

Comment: @marmot `circle(1)` is the same as `circle[radius=1]` which is the same as `circle[x radius=1,y radius=1]` which is the ellipse that goes throw the points `+x-vector` and `+y-vector`. You can check this with `circle[x={(1,1)},radius=1]`. In the manual `radius` is not a *`dimension`* but a *`value`* because it can be *`dimension`* or *`factor`*.

Comment: Well, I disagree. This is all under the question "Different dimensions with shift and xshift". My take is that the OP is wondering that, if they use dimensionless numbers, dimensions will be appended and they are different in different contexts. I agree with this observation and give another example in which `cm` get appended. If it was always a factor, why would `\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);` work.

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts:

- You're not doing anything incorrect.
- Is it a bug? It is not a bug in the sense that the program crashes or that the result deviates from what one may expect from the manual. So my take it is not a bug.
- The default unit for coordinates is `cm`, so `at (1,0)` and `at (1cm,0)` are equivalent. That's why the shift={(5,0)} and shift={(5cm,0)} can be used interchangedly.
- Is this not the only situation where `cm` is the unit. Another situation in which the default unit is cm is a cricle, so `\draw (0,0) circle(1);` gives you a circle of radius `1cm`, similarly for arcs.
- But for "most" other situations the default unit is `pt`.

Comment: marmot, see Kpym's answer, `pt` is the default unit for length.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well, depends on how you define default unit. From the OP's post I thought their definition is what is inserted when you do not specify the unit. If you adopt this definition, it is not the case for, say, circles and arcs. I would even make the stronger statement that, in view of the behavior of circles etc., the statement "In TikZ always the default unit for length values is `pt`." is not entirely correct. What is a radius if not a length (scale)?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it is considered a sort of polar coordinate.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, sure. I really thin it boils down how you interpret "I discovered that there is a different default dimension in shift and xshift.". My interpretation is that the question concerns the observation that, if you do not specify the dimensions, Ti*k*Z will insert some for you, and the dimension Ti*k*Z inserts depends on the context. All I am saying is that this is true, and that the dimension automatically inserted in the case of a circle is also `cm`, whereas it is `pt` for most other situations.

Comment: The syntax `\draw (0,0) circle (1)` is an old syntax that still works but is deprecated. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303130/138900

Comment: @CarLaTeX I'd like to ask you to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799 and then re-evaluate Kpym's and my statements.

Comment: @marmot I think it's too difficult for my level

Answer (score 2):

An example that ilustrate @Kpym's nice answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,3) ;
  \node (a) at (0,3) {a};
  \node (b) at (0,2) {b};
  \node (c) at (0,1) {c};
  \node (d) at (0,0) {d};
  \begin{scope}[x={(2,1)}] % change the vector x 
  \node[xshift=2cm] at (a) {aa}; % 2cm to the right
  \node[shift={(2cm,0)}] at (b) {bb}; % 2cm to the right and 0pt to the top
  \node[xshift=2] at (c) {cc}; % 2pt to the right
  \node[shift={(2,0)}] at (d) {dd}; % 2x+0y
  \draw[blue] circle[radius=0.5]; % 0.5 is interpreted as xradius =0.5x and yradius =0.5 y
  \draw[red] circle[radius=0.5cm]; % .0.5cm is interpreted as xradius=yradius=0.5cm

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]